# Python - Conditional / Metadata driven class import and execution

Tags: python, mongodb, class, metadata

I'm having some difficulty achieving a metadata driven approach to scheduling code execution.

Basically, I wish to build a queue of work items to process which are tagged as a specific type.   There are associated 'consumer' classes and methods which I want to process the work item.

End objective is to have a fully database driven approach where jobs enter queue of a specific type and the associated classes are instantiated to process the job.

For now, I'll just work with a dict (proc_dict).

```
queue_sources=['queue1','queue2','queue3']

for source in queue_sources:
    collection=jq[source]
    for item in collection.find({}):
        schedule_type = item['schedule']
        date_last_run = item['ts']['date_last_run']
        item['job_type']=source

    if schedule_type=='daily':
        days=1
    elif schedule_type=='weekly':
        days=7

    if date_last_run is None:
        jobqueue.pub(item)

    elif date_last_run  > datetime.now()-timedelta(days=days):
        jobqueue.pub(item)

    else:
        module_logger.debug("Job does not meet criteria: ",item)
        module_logger.debug(" -- schedule type: ",schedule_type)
        module_logger.debug(" -- date last run: ",date_last_run)



def process_schedule(item):
    proc_dict={"queue1":["s_type1","type1_class","type1_method"]
              ,"queue2":["s_type2","type2_class","type2_method"]
              ,"queue3":["s_type3","type3_class","type3_method"]
              }

    job_type=item['job_type']

    if job_type in proc_dict.keys():
            consumer=[item][job_type][0]
            consumer_class=[item][job_type][1]
            consumer_method=[item][job_type][2]
            from consumer import consumer_class

            ...instantiate class

            ...do stuff with item
```

A job would look something like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f6490b816c7bcb39375b8d"), 
    "data" : {
        "ts" : {
            "date_last_modified" : ISODate("2017-10-29T20:42:50.801+0000"), 
            "date_last_run" : null
        }, 
        "manufacturer" : "xxxxx", 
        "status" : "active", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59f63d5da54d752e56150af7"), 
        "schedule" : "weekly", 
        "manufacturer_type" : "Business", 
        "url" : "https://www.xxxx/", 
        "job_type" : "queue1"
    }, 
    "status" : "waiting", 
    "ts" : {
        "created" : ISODate("2017-10-29T21:32:59.130+0000"), 
        "started" : null, 
        "done" : null
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to understand:

1. If should be persevering with this kind of pattern
2. If so, how to instantiate and call the classes on the fly

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bit more research uncovers:

```
importlib.
```

Thus it becomes something like:

```
    if job_type in proc_dict.keys():
        consumer=[item][job_type][0]
        consumer_class=[item][job_type][1]
        consumer_method=[item][job_type][2]

        imported_class=importlib.__import__(consumer_class)
        imported_class_instance=imported_class()
        imported_class_instance.consumer_method(item)
```